# How to make a CheckBoxList with different number of items in each column?

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a CheckBoxList in my page with 28 ListItems inside of it. When I put the RepeatColumns="2", my CheckBoxList is split in two columns of 14 items. What I want to do is make the first column with 17 items, while the second has the remaining 11 items. How can I modify my code to show uneven columns in a CheckBoxList?

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="rblPraticasTemasSaude" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="2">
        <asp:ListItem Text="01" Value="01"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="02" Value="02"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="03" Value="03"></asp:ListItem>
<%-- more ListItems --%>
        <asp:ListItem Text="27" Value="27"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="28" Value="28"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `RepeatColumns` attribute to 17, and then use this function

```
function rotate() {
            $("#<%= rblPraticasTemasSaude.ClientID %>").each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var newrows = [];
                $this.find("tr").each(function() {
                    var i = 0;
                    $(this).find("td").each(function() {
                        i++;
                        if (newrows[i] === undefined) { newrows[i] = $("<tr></tr>"); }
                        newrows[i].append($(this));
                    });
                });
                $this.find("tr").remove();
                $.each(newrows, function() {
                    $this.append(this);
                });
            });
            return false;
        }

        rotate();
```

You need to reference jQuery before the `rotate` function

Comment: Your solution totally works. After that, I just had to change the property RepeatDirection from "Vertical" to "Horizontal", and my CheckBoxList became ordered the way I needed. Thanks.