# Data driven year list not displaying correctly with datalist

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I'm having an issue getting my year list check boxes to line as my lead requested.

Currently it displays like this

```
1980 1984 1987 1990
1981 1985 1988 1991
1982 1986 1989 1992
1983
```

I need to make it look like this

```
1980 1984 1988 1992
1981 1985 1989
1982 1986 1990
1983 1987 1991
```

He wants the columns to fill out except for the last one.  The number of years changes so I can't hard code them.

I'm currently using a  datalist with my data coming from an oracle procedure just selecting out years.

```
    <asp:DataList 
          ID="dlYears"              
          width="100%"
          runat="server" 
          GridLines=Horizontal 
          RepeatColumns="4" 
          RepeatDirection="Horizontal"               
          Font-Bold="False" 
          Font-Italic="False"               
          Font-Overline="False" 
          Font-Strikeout="False" 
          Font-Underline="False" 
          ShowFooter="False" 
          CellPadding="0">             
            <ItemStyle cssclass="text_11" />
            <HeaderTemplate>      
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="heading">    
                  <td colspan="4">
                    <table style="width:100%;">
                      <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;YEARS
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;">
                          <table style="width:100%;">
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibYearsAll" ToolTip="Check all years" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/circle_blue.png" onclick="ibYearsAll_Click"  />                                    
                              &nbsp;
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibYearsNone" ToolTip="Uncheck all years" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/circlered.png" onclick="ibYearsNone_Click" />                                    
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                              </td>                                  
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>   
              </HeaderTemplate>          
              <ItemTemplate>                    
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkYear" runat="server" Checked=false Enabled="false" />
                <asp:Label class="text_11" ID="lblYear" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"year") %>'></asp:Label>            
                </td>            
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

I have searched and found similar questions, but not with an answer that has worked.  Would a repeater do what I'm looking for with the check boxes?  This will be more work to change the existing code, but if it works then I will do it.

Thank you

Comment: Just a question: Why did you use the oracle tag?

Comment: I was trying to be thorough and I wanted to include all the tech I was using.  The query that pulls my info is a oracle procedure.  Should I exclude it?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I think it would be better without the tag. I'm watching new questions tagged oracle, and I cannot help you in any way. Also, it will not help people with the same difficulty to find you question.

Comment: I updated the question and removed oracle.  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You should only tag things which are relevant to the specific problem. People with expertise in those technologies follow the tags and can help if the question is relevant. But  tagging everything in your stack whether relevant or not just creates noise

Comment: As to your question, a repeater would give you more flexibility over the presentation, yes

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the suggestions here: [How to make a CheckBoxList with different number of items in each column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750742/how-to-make-a-checkboxlist-with-different-number-of-items-in-each-column) to generate my checkboxlist with the years flowing in the right direction and having the first 3 columns full with the 4th having the remainder of years.

Thank you